# Pentaho CDE Dashboard Component Style Editing

Tags: javascript, pentaho, dashboard, pentaho-cde

I'm quite new to Pentaho dashboard develop and i have a problem with the component style.

For example, I added a table component to my dashboard.

In the "Advanced Properties -> Style" option of this table component, I select "bootstrap". Okay then the table component is automatically added some bootstrap style classes.

But, I want to remove one of those classes. I want to use jQuery.removeClass() to implement this but I don't know where should I put my js sentences.

Further more, if i want to do some other operation towards the generated table component using js, where should i put my js sentences.

I do not understand the workflow of pentaho cde dashboard so this question may seems a little silly. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put your code in **Draw Function**.

=> Your using Table component. By using java script code or jquery code you can manipulate the data in table component.

**Example:**
 1. You want to sum of the row values.
 2. You can hide the columns and rows.

**Note:** If you put some code in draw function. table component has convert sql result in to HTML table. Its like a normal HTML table.

Thank you.

Comment: Yeah! done this and it's okay now. 
Thank! By the way, do you know where i could learn about the cde dashboard? Especially the document of it's component and use of data source... I find really few about these.

Comment: I think there is no material for dashboards. I have few url please refere these => https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cW8YzwC2uNU   =>
http://pentaho-bi-suite.blogspot.in/. Its better to do some R&D, you can understand better things. Thank you.

Comment: Hi i have another problem TT. I use the method above to create a table, in draw function i create a <div id="testID"> with id , I set the htmlObject of a chart component to be "testID". this div did appears but the chart did not appear. I think it's because when the chart component is created, the draw function has not been excuted so that there's no testID div at that time. The testID div appears after the chart is trying to be drawn. Do you know how may I let the chart created inside the testID div? Really thanks!

Comment: Sorry chart side i don't know.